# url rewrite for the file extension in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I need help in rewriting the url in Azure APIM, where my scenario is, I have this url `https://azure.websites.net/api/hello.json` in this url i'm trying to fetch the data from that file hello.json. But when i call this url i don't want to include .json extension, my expected url should look like this `https://azure.websites.net/api/hello`. when I call this url the data should be loaded in my client side. can anyone please help me on how to do this scenario. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbound policies -rewrite URL template for the Azure APIM API to replace the client URL.

We can modify the rewrite URL template given in this [Azure APIM GitHub Doc](https://jiasli.github.io/azure-notes/api-management/sample-policies.html) as per our requirement:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Api.Path+context.Operation.UrlTemplate.Replace("/*",""),""))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```

Place your original URL and the new URL in the below format:

```
<set-header name="Location" exists-action="override">
<value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().Replace("http://","https://"))</value>
</set-header>
```

[image]

This should be applied on the API Inbound Policies level given in above GitHub doc of Azure APIM Policies.